# Имитация нажатия клавиш в sh скрипте

Tags: ubuntu

Мне нужно, чтобы скрипт после создания screen'а выходил из него, т.е. сработало бы нажатие клавиш ctrl a + d. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не обязательно, для того чтобы сделать screenshot, куда-то заходить, можно прямо в скрипте сделать снимок и записать в файл, инструментов  много, искать в поиске.

Comment: Я имел ввиду утилиту screen (с помощью которой можно несколько терминалов создавать)

Comment: Ты про `xdotool`?